# $http.jsonp requests are gettings canceled

Tags: javascript, angularjs, salesforce, jsonp, apex-code

I swear this was working earlier, took a break, and now its not working again...

I'm building an AngularJS app that connects to a custom public REST api I've created with Salesforce. I've tested the REST api via curl and apigee.com and the data is being returned properly. The problem occurs when I attempt to call the same endpoint via Angulars $http.jsonp() method. When I attempt to do this the request is canceled, according to Chromes Network monitor.

**Angular Factory:**

```
angular.module('SalesforceService', [], function($provide){

    $provide.factory('$salesforce', function($http, $q){

        return {
            login: function(email, password){

                var endpoint  = 'https://merchant.dev1.cs15.force.com/freelance/services/apexrest/FreelanceService?name=Jonathan&callback=JSON_CALLBACK';
                var deferred = $q.defer();

                console.log('...calling salesforce...');
                $http.jsonp(endpoint)               
                .success(function(data){
                    console.log('--SALESFORCE RESPONSE:');
                    console.log(data);

                    deferred.resolve(data);
                }).error(function(data, status, headers, config){
                    console.log('---SALESFORCE ERROR:');
                    console.log(data);
                    console.log(status);
                    console.log(headers());
                    console.log(config);

                    deferred.reject('An error occurred when attempting to login.');
                });

                return deferred.promise;
            }
        };

    });

})
```

I then call this service in one of my controllers via $salesforce.login()...

**Custom Salesforce REST Class:**

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/FreelanceService')
global class FreelanceService 
{
    global class TestObject{
        public String message;

        public TestObject(String message){
            this.message = message;
        }
    }

    @HttpGet
    global static void goGet()
    {
        String name = RestContext.request.params.get('name');

        TestObject o = new TestObject('Hello ' + name);

        RestContext.response.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        RestContext.response.responseBody = formatResponse(o);
    }

    public static blob formatResponse(TestObject obj)
    {
        //instantiate string to be returned
        String response;

        //get callback parameter from url
        String callback = RestContext.request.params.get('callback');

        //return JSON wrapped in function if a callback parameter exists
        if(callback!=null)
        {
            response = callback + '('+JSON.serialize(obj)+')';
        }
        else
        {
            response = JSON.serialize(obj);
        }

        return blob.valueOf(response);
    }
}
```

For the life of me I cannot figure out why this isn't working... Any ideas?

Comment: Difficult to say. So is the jsonp call going to an endpoint you control or is it out of your control? One 'odd' thing in your code is that you create a deferred object for your http call. You don't actually have to do that, because $http itself returns a promise

Comment: I created a deferred object so I could do filtering on the data within the service before injecting the result into any controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out because the Salesforce REST service was being served from a Sandbox instead of Production, Chrome was automatically canceling the request because of a certificate name mismatch error.

From the Salesforce Sites Implementation Guide:

> Only production organizations have the valid secure.force.com SSL
>   certificates to access sites using HTTPS. Note: If a site within a
>   sandbox (non-production) organization is accessed using HTTPS, a
>   certificate name mismatch warning may appear